# zooming and panning pdf file in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to zoom into a pdf file and after that move around the file with UIPanGestureRecogniser. The pdf file has only 1 page.

I've searched for the last hour on the web and all i come across is overly complicated for my needs ( book readers and such ). I'm new in iOS programming and i do not know how to modify those projects to suit my purposes.

My idea is this: add the pdf file to a UIView and then manipulate the UIView ( and while the view is transforming ) the pdf file redraws.

Where would one begin making something like this? Is it even possible?

If not ..do i need to use a WebView or UIScrollView or something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out this sample code from Apple, [ZoomingPDFViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). Fair warning, this is a complicated topic, using a UIWebView is the easy way out but you lose a lot of control over how it looks and renders.